# Merge data of two file depending upon key attribute in Java

Tags: java, arrays, file, java.util.scanner, filewriter

I have two data files data1.txt and data2.txt. data1.txt consist of 3 Column and 10 rows and data2.txt consist of 4 column and 4 rows.

The structure of data1.txt is

```
1.0  1.235   2.3145
2.0  0.325   3.2145
3.0  1.568   4.0215
4.0  0.389   1.2354
7.0  2.054   1.3247
8.0  1.111   2.6570
10.0  1.786   1.2587
11.0  5.628   0.2354
13.0  4.897   1.6542
15.0  1.230   1.0210
```

The structure of data2.txt is

```
5.0  .... .... ....
6.0  .... .... .... 
9.0  .... .... ....
12.0 .... .... ....
```

So as per data set 5.0,6.0 is missing from data1.txt which is in data2.txt. 9.0 is missing from data1.txt which is present in data2.txt and so on. I want to insert those missing values in data1.txt. So the output of data file after insertion will be

Data1.txt

```
 1.0  1.235   2.3145
 2.0  0.325   3.2145
 3.0  1.568   4.0215
 4.0  0.389   1.2354 
 5.0  .... .... ....
 6.0  .... .... .... 
 7.0  2.054   1.3247
 8.0  1.111   2.6570 
 9.0  .... .... ....
 10.0  1.786   1.2587
 11.0  5.628   0.2354 
 and so on
```

My code is like that

```
public class F1 {
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception{
    Scanner X =new Scanner(new File("C:\\data1.txt"));
    Scanner Y =new Scanner(new File("C:\\data2.txt"));
    double a=0.0,b=0.0,c,d=0.0,e=0.0,f,g,h;
    List<Double>list1=new ArrayList<>();
    List<Double>list4=new ArrayList<>();
    double arr[]=new double[10];
    double arr1[]=new double[5];
        while (X.hasNext()) {
            a = X.nextDouble();
            list1.add(a);
            b = X.nextDouble();
            c = X.nextDouble();

        }

        while(Y.hasNext()) {
            d = Y.nextDouble();
            list4.add(d);
            e = Y.nextDouble();

            f = Y.nextDouble();

            g = Y.nextDouble();


        }

    for(int i=0;i<list1.size();i++) {

        arr[i]=list1.get(i);//Store value into an array
        }
        for(int j=0;j<list4.size();j++){
            arr1[j]=list4.get(j);//Store value into an array
        }
        for(int k=0;k<arr.length;k++){
       // Appending condition
        }
}
```

}

How could I proceed? Is there need any insertion sort or any if statement for appending? How did Printwriter work here?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not clear to me. Do you want a solution of array index out of bound ? OR do you want merging solution.

For index out of bound - you can have a check inside array element comparison logic as:

```
for (int k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
    if (k == list4.size() - 1 && arr[k] < arr1[k]) {
        // error because array dimension mismatch

        double a1 = 3 + 5; // Any operation
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to merge Solution.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are not confusing your arrays and lists. You have defined your arrays like this:

```
double arr[]=new double[10];
double arr1[]=new double[5];
 for(int j=0;j<list4.size();j++){
     arr1[j]=list4.get(j);//Store value into an array
 }
```

and obviously you are inserting list4 elements containing 10 elements in arr1 which is defined to contain only 5 elements - this is definitely going to throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

For merging, Can you take a Map with key as first digit and whole value again as value. for example
1.0  1.235   2.3145
1.0 as key and this whole as Value. Now you can sort the map based on key. This will put record on sorted way and you can do the further calculation. Is this what you wanted?